# Rspec is painfully slow with Ruby on Rails 3 + Devise + Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm using Rspec to test our cancan ability.rb file. While the app runs very fast in dev mode, rpsec is painfully slow and the logs don't show long db or view rendering times. How do you go about diagnosing why Rspec is running so slow?

UPDATE - In the gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'debugger'
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'rack', '1.4.1'
```

Comment: Do you use guard and spork?

Comment: Updating the q with the gemfile

Comment: Well using guard (https://github.com/guard/guard) and spork (https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) will automate your specs and make them run faster (because you load Rails environment only once).

Comment: "Slow" is extremely subjective. would you run with "time rspec spec" and update with the output?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, more than 2 maximum 3 seconds should be considered slow. It's 21 century outside, even phones have dual-core processors already.

Comment: @Green that's wholly unrealistic for an entire test suite for a Rails application built in the 'normal' way.

Answer (score 1):

Most preferred way for me is set up [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) and [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork), because while guard runs only the test which are affecting for the changed file, spork pre-loads for better performance.

The following screencasts will get you up and running in no time:

[Spork](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork)

[Guard](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard)